# XCode equivalent of Visual Studio clipboard ring?

Tags: xcode

In Visual Studio there is a [clipboard ring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301782(v=vs.71).aspx) and you can CTRL + SHIFT + V to cycle through the last 15 strings to be cut or copied.

Is there an equivalent in XCode?

Google seems to say no but maybe XCode doesn't call it a ring and I'm just not using the right query.